# How do I make my animated gif's size smaller (HTML)

Tags: html

```
<H1>Search Engines</H1>
<B><a href="http://www.yahoo.co.uk/">Yahoo</a></B><br>
<I><a href="https://www.excite.com/">Excite</a></I><br>
<U><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></U><br>
<B><font color="#000000">Note: Click on the links, they will take you to the following websites! </font></B>
<H1></H1>
<img src ="Google.gif">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <H1>Search Engines</H1>
<B><a href="http://www.yahoo.co.uk/">Yahoo</a></B><br>
<I><a href="https://www.excite.com/">Excite</a></I><br>
<U><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></U><br>
<B><font color="#000000">Note: Click on the links, they will take you to the following websites! </font></B>
<H1></H1>
<img src ="Google.gif">

</body>
</html>

Comment: I have a gif there but its not visible.

Comment: @Quentin, That was a incredibly rude comment but, I have just started learning HTML yesterday so please don't expect me to know everything. However, if you can improve it, go ahead. by smaller, I meant reduce te size of the GIF. Just a bit of feedback: We all are still learning.

Comment: I've got my answer, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add width and height at the image. you can add it at html, or the css.

#### adding width and height at the HTML

```css
img {
border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<H1>Search Engines</H1>
<B><a href="http://www.yahoo.co.uk/">Yahoo</a></B><br>
<I><a href="https://www.excite.com/">Excite</a></I><br>
<U><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></U><br>
<B><font color="#000000">Note: Click on the links, they will take you to the following websites! </font></B>
<H1></H1>
<img src ="Google.gif" width="300px" height="300px"> <!--change the width and height value-->
```

#### adding width and height at the CSS

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width:300px;/* change this value */
  height:300px;/* change this value */
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<H1>Search Engines</H1>
<B><a href="http://www.yahoo.co.uk/">Yahoo</a></B><br>
<I><a href="https://www.excite.com/">Excite</a></I><br>
<U><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></U><br>
<B><font color="#000000">Note: Click on the links, they will take you to the following websites! </font></B>
<H1></H1>
<img src ="Google.gif" >
```